# Mesibo -- Turned off On-Premise But still the webhook call going to On-Premise IP

Tags: mesibo

mesibo

I turned on the On-Premise option.

[image]

Then my webhook call going to mesibo.js:73 WebSocket connection to 'wss://*.*.*.*:5443/' failed: from web-browser

ANd I turned it off due to network error.

[image]

Still my webhook call going to same Ip as before but not to mesibo webhook.But i didn't check the autofall back option first,But when turned off the on-premise I checked the autofall backoption and clicked in save option.

And all the users are showing as offline.

How can I get back on using the mesibo cloud again and all the users should be online.

The error looks like this

[image]

Comment: If your web client was connected to on-premise, it will try a couple of times before moving back to the cloud. This is done for performance and security.  Also, note that when you use on-premise, the console has no access to your database, and hence all users will show offline.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Not a couple of times the issue is coming continuously. Please refer to the newly added image in this post. And what is the status 2 means.

Comment: @mesibo Can u Please respond